# How to reconfigure grub

Tags: linux, arch-linux, grub, manjaro

I have been using Manjaro Linux for 4 months now, with the KDE desktop environment. Today I woke up with itch: I wanted to test Manjaro with XFCE, so I downloaded it and installed it, without knowing that it would overwrite the boot loader of my main OS. I tried to find ways to recover what I did, and I didn't really find any, so I decided to delete the new OS, hoping that would fix it and I would be able to boot into my older Manjaro: it didn't work.

Now, when I try to boot my computer, I can choose to boot into Manjaro, but after that a black screen with the following text appears:

```
error: symbol `grub_file_filters_all` not found.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

If I run `set`, the output will be:

```
cmdpath=(hd0,gpt1)/EFI/Manjaro
lang=
locale_dir=
prefix=(hd0,gpt5)/boot/grub
root=hd0,gpt5
secondary_locale_dir=
```

I know that my Manjaro partition is the gpt8, and it's encrypted using luks encryption. I tried to change the prefix and root to:

```
prefix=(hd0,gpt8)/boot/grub
root=hd0,gpt8
```

But it didn't work because it could not recognize the file system. I tried to use the cryptomount command, but it says that it does not exist.

I'm not sure if I can fix the mess that I made, and if it's possible, I don't have the knowledge to do it. Hopefully someone here with more experience could help me.

Comment: Note for next time: XFCE and KDE are just programs (well collections of programs). You can just install them, you can have them both installed on the same OS, along with 10 other desktop environments. You can have different users logged in using different desktops, at the same time. You can even switch desktop environments without even logging out, or closing apps.